# Where to add custom js file

Tags: magento-1.8, extensions

Can anyone let me know what is good practice for adding custom js file in a custom plugin? 
should I add it to skin's js folder or should i add it to root's js folder?

Answer (score 5):

Don't add it to the root folder if you just need the js file in your plugin.

A practicable workflow for me is locating such frontend files within `skin/frontend/base/default/js/...` and link to them via an extension. This way it will be available through to every theme you are using.

Create the module **YOURMODULE** within the namespace **YOURNAMESPACE**.

**Module's config file:     `app/code/CODEPOOL/YOURNAMESPACE/YOURMODULE/etc/config.xml`**

to link to a specific layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <YOURNAMESPACE_YOURMODULE>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </YOURNAMESPACE_YOURMODULE>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <arena>
                    <file>YOURMODULE/YOURMODULE.xml</file>
                    <!-- path to your layout file -->
                </arena>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

**Module's layout file: `app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/YOURNAMESPACE/YOURMODULE/YOURMODULE.xml`**

to include custom js/css files

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addItem">
                <type>skin_css</type>
                <name>css/YOURNAMESPACE/YOURMODULE/YOURMODULE.css</name>
                <!-- path to your css file -->
            </action>
            <action method="addItem">
                <type>skin_js</type>
                <name>js/YOURNAMESPACE/YOURMODULE/YOURMODULE.js</name>
                <!-- path to your js file -->
            </action>
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

**Module's css/js files: `/skin/frontend/base/default/css/YOURNAMESPACE/YOURMODULE/YOURMODULE.css`
`/skin/frontend/base/default/js/YOURNAMESPACE/YOURMODULE/YOURMODULE.js`**

Answer (score 3):

If you plan to add a library or library part (like a carousel or something like that) that can be used independently from the theme you should add it in the `js` folder.

If you have something that depends heavily on the markup add it in the skin js folder.
For example if you have a js that should do the following, add it in the skin js folder.

```
document.observe("dom:loaded", function() {
  $('some-div-id-here').hide(); //depends on a div id.
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The `js` folder in normally considered similar to the lib folder and used mainly for complete javascript libraries.

The `skin_js` is normally used for your module's JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Create alocal.xml file inside layout folder

```
Path: /app/design/frontend/yourtheme/default/layout/local.xml
```

And use the below code to add custom Js file:

```
<layout>  
 <default>
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="addJs">
            <script>custom-script.js</script>
        </action>
    </reference>
</default>
</layout>
```